# "Los culpables son ellos", duda sobre análisis sintáctico

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

Mientras estaba consultando [un sitio de la RAE](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20t%C3%B3nicos) por una duda sobre los pronombres tónicos, me surge una duda aún mayor cuando encuentro lo siguiente:

> Los pronombres personales tónicos son aquellos que pueden funcionar como sujeto (TÚ sabrás), como atributo (Los culpables son **ELLOS**) ...

¿Por qué como atributo? ¿Cómo puedo distinguir en este caso si es un atributo o un sujeto si las oraciones

> Los culpables son ellos.

> Ellos son los culpables.

son equivalentes? Mas aún, tengo la convicción de que es válido afirmar que "ellos" es el sujeto y que "los culpables" es el atributo en ambas oraciones. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esta discrepancia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En las oraciones con verbo copulativo, suele darse el "efecto espejo", en que sujeto y predicativo pueden alternarse.

El sujeto será aquello de lo que se viene hablando, y el predicativo será la información nueva. Por ejemplo:

A. Me parecen dos personas maravillosas.

B. ¿Maravillosas? Ellos son los culpables de que estemos como estamos. (Ellos: sujeto / los culpables ...: predicativo)

A. Los culpables de esta situación somos nosotros.

B. No estoy de acuerdo. Los culpables son ellos. (Los culpables: sujeto / ellos: predicativo)

En [este sitio](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Linguistik/o/ORACIONES%20COPULATIVAS%20o%20ATRIBUTIVAS.htm#:%7E:text=Las%20oraciones%20copulativas%20est%C3%A1n%20formadas,el%20elemento%20relevante%20del%20predicado.&text=es%20el%20verbo%20copulativo%20ser.), podemos leer que estas oraciones se llaman "ecuativas":

> **Sujeto y atributo**
>
> Cuando el atributo es un sustantivo con artículo, cabe la duda respecto a su función. En oraciones como *Juan es el médico* y *El médico es Juan*, podemos ver respuestas a preguntas como *¿Quién es el médico?* o *¿Quién es Juan?* También podría contestarse a la primera con *Juan lo es* (donde el referente lo señala que el médico funciona como atributo); a la segunda se respondería simplemente con *Es el médico*, donde tampoco se discierne entre las dos funciones de sujeto explícito y de atributo. No sería muy normal contestar *Lo es el médico*, con lo referido a Juan como atributo. Se ha hablado en estos casos de oraciones ecuativas.»
>
> [Alarcos Llorach, Emilio: Gramática de la lengua española. Madrid: Espasa-Calpe, 1994, § 361-362]
>
> **La posición del sujeto en las oraciones copulativas con ser**
>
> Hay un único caso en el que la posición del sujeto puede influir en su reconocimiento. Se trata de las oraciones con el verbo *ser* en las que tanto lo que aparece delante como detrás del verbo podría ser sujeto. En estos casos, se suele considerar sujeto el elemento que aparece en primer lugar.
>
> La capital de Italia es Roma. [El sujeto es *la capital de Italia*.]
>
> *Roma es la capital de Italia.* [El sujeto es *Roma*.]
>
> No obstante, en enunciados como *el problema eres tú* o *¿qué es una quena?*, los sujetos respectivos son *tú* y *una quena*.
>
> [Gómez Torrego, L.:  Análisis sintáctico. Teoría y práctica. Madrid: Ediciones SM, 2004, § 7.5]